# mysql - how to update and replace ignoring case

Tags: mysql, sql

How to update columns - case insensitive ??

If I run the query below it brings back 62 records as expected:

```
select entity_id 
from field_data_body 
where body_value like '%mailto:iss.servicedesk@example.com%';
```

> Returns 62 Records

I am trying to update these records so that `iss.servicedesk@example.com` is replaced with `http://iss.servicedesk.example.com` using the following query:

```
update field_data_body
SET body_value = REPLACE(body_value,'%mailto:iss.servicedesk@example.com%',
                        'http://iss.servicedesk.example.com');
```

Unfortunately it is only updating 52 records as it is running a case sensitive query e.g. `Iss.Servicedesk@example.com` is not recognized in the above query.

How can I run the above update query but make it case insensitive to pick up all tables I am wishing to update ?

I have updated the query below - its runs but does not find any results to update when I know there are links that need updating :

```
update `field_data_body` SET `body_value` = REPLACE(body_value,'%mailto:iss.servicedesk@example.com%','https://iss.servicedesk.example.com')
where LOWER(CONVERT( body_value USING latin1)) like '%mailto:iss.servicedesk@example.com%'
```

Any advise on what I need to do to fix it so it runs correctly ?

Answer (score 4):

Use `UPPER()` or `LOWER()` function with the query.

Answer (score 2):

just an FYI: LOWER and UPPER dont work on BINARY, VARBINARY and BLOB. If your field is of one of these type, you'll need to convert the string to a nonbinary string by using CONVERT:

```
 LOWER(CONVERT(@str USING latin1))
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to implement this in my query - im a bit new to this ?

Comment: where LOWER(CONVERT(body_value USING latin1)) like '%mailto:iss.servicedesk@example.com%';

Comment: I tried this - the query runs but does not return any updated results but I know there are tables that need updating - have I got the syntax wrong:  update `field_data_body` SET `body_value` = REPLACE(body_value,'%mailto:iss.servicedesk@example.com%','https://iss.servicedesk.example.com')
where LOWER(CONVERT( body_value USING latin1)) like '%mailto:iss.servicedesk@example.com%'

Comment: maybe latin1 is not your collation, do you know which is? Or maybe if you try the query without it

Comment: utf8 it appears to be ..... I tried update `field_data_body` SET `body_value` = REPLACE(body_value,'%mailto:iss.servicedesk@example.com%','https://iss.servicedesk.example.com')
where LOWER(CONVERT( body_value USING utf8)) like '%mailto:iss.servicedesk@example.com%' and the query ran like before but did not update any records ...running the query without putting in the collation type does not work ...